# Finding deflection of an electron through 2 charged plates when given initial velocity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism

I've been trying to relate the initial velocity of an electron to the deflection created based on the electric field between 1 pair of plates. The 2nd half of page 3 of [this pdf](https://sun.iwu.edu/%7Egspaldin/DeflectionByE-field.pdf) is what I'm concerned with. Now, I was trying to derive y (the deflection distance), where e is elementary charge, and let $\theta$ be the trajectory of the electron immediately after leaving the plates ($\sin{\theta}$ is equal to $\frac{\Delta y_1}{L}$ and **probably** equal to $\frac{v_y}{v}$ in the diagram, this could be part of the misunderstanding).

**Explaining my approach for change in y-position through the plates only:**
using $F=ma$ and $F=qE$ and $a=\frac{qE}{m}$ and $t=\frac{L}{v_x}$ where L is the length of a plate (total horizontal distance that the electric field between the plates acts on the electron) and $v_x$ is the initial velocity I get:
$$\Delta y_1=\frac{1}{2}\frac{qE}{m}\biggl(\frac{L}{v_x}\biggr)^2$$ by kinematics.

**Accounting for the remaining distance (not between plates):**
My thought was that $\Delta y_1=\frac{eEL^2}{2mv_x^2}$ is the change in the y-position while between the plates, so the remaining $D\sin{\theta}$ would be the extra change in y-position **after leaving the plates**:
$$y=D\sin{\theta} + \frac{eEL^2}{2mv_x^2}$$

vs what the pdf has:
$$y=\frac{eEL}{mv_x^2}\biggl(D+\frac{L}{2}\biggr)$$

This is *almost* the same as what I have, the only difference is I have $D\sin{\theta}$ instead of $D\frac{eEL^2}{2mv_x^2}$ and I'm trying to figure out my misunderstanding.

**Can someone please explain where my misunderstanding is? I can't tell why my derivation is incorrect?**

Comment: You have not shown the steps in the derivation, so how can anyone help? You should include that. Cheers.

Comment: @josephh I wouldn't have thought it impossible to help if I didn't show each step of derivation. I'll try and add some

Comment: There may be some concept that you have misinterpreted, so it'll be easier to identify. Thanks.

Comment: @josephh Agreed, I didn't realize how vague my question was until I re-read it. I added some more explanation

Comment: @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins I have expanded my answer and agree with you comments about the other answer in which the =$y$ acceleration is assumed to be constant for the whole passage of the electron through the apparatus..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I need to write another answer to explain my original answer in more detail and to agree with the comments that @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins made with regard to the answer @josephh produced which I believe to be erroneous as it assumes a constant acceleration in the $y$ direction both inside and outside the electric field.

The deflection part of the experimental arrangement is as follows.

[image]

The motion of the electron consists of two parts.
Between $A$ and $B$ where there is a uniform electric field in the $-y$ direction an electron is accelerated in the $y$ direction with a constant acceleration of $\frac{eE}{m}$ and moves with a constant velocity $v_{\rm x}$ in the $x$ direction as there is no force on the electron in that direction.
Between $B$ and $C$ the electron moves with a constant velocity $v$ with components $v_{\rm x}$ and $v_{\rm y}$ on the assumption that there is no electric field in this region.

For region $AB$, applying $y = ut + \frac 12 at^2 \Rightarrow y_{\rm AB} = \frac 12 \frac {eE}{m} \left ( \frac {L}{v_{\rm x}}\right )^2$

The motion of an electron in the region $BC$ is linear and inclined at an angle $\theta$ to the straight through trajectory with $\tan \theta = \frac{v_{\rm y}}{v_{x}}$ the time taken to traverse this region is $t_{\rm BC}=\frac{D}{v_{\rm x}}$.

Now the $y$ component of velocity on entering the region $BC$ is $v_{\rm y} = \frac {eE}{m} t_{\rm AB}$ where $t_{\rm AB}= \frac{L}{v_{\rm x}}$.

So the extra deflection in region $BC$ is $y_{\rm BC} = \frac {eE}{m} \cdot \frac{L}{v_{\rm x}}\cdot \frac{D}{v_{\rm x}}$.

Hence $y_{\rm AC} = \dfrac{eEL}{mv_{\rm x}^2}\left (D+\dfrac{L}{2}\right)$

Comment: The angle $θ$ is not small, so this approximation is not valid (indeed if it was you'd find it difficult measuring the deflection distance on a CRO - and the angle $θ$ is not referenced anywhere in the original document. $θ$ is something the OP has defined in the same way you have, but this angle is not needed and unnecessarily complicates the problem.

Comment: No, it’s certainly not equivalent. I don’t know how you concluded that tbh. Cheers.

Comment: I appreciate this answer, thank you for showing me how to deal with the $D\sin{\theta}$ thing I created. Like @josephh said, I didn't need theta, and you've shown me what I should've done. My miscommunication with joseph was due to the author assuming $BC$ was "in the field", joseph was showing me how the author got the equation they got

Comment: Now that I think about it *again*, the author didn't assume $BC$ to be still affected by the field.

Answer (score 1):

What you did here was take the time that the charge moves from start of the plate to the end of it, which you had as $\frac{L}{v_x}$ *But* the  the time of flight of the electron to the *screen* is $\frac{L+D}{v_x}$ because $v_x$ stays the same from the point where the electron is released until it reaches the screen (not just the end of the plates). This is significant in finding the correct equation.

So
$$t=\frac{L+D}{v_x}$$ meaning $$\Delta y=\frac{1}{2}\frac{eE}{m}\biggl(\frac{L+D}{v_x}\biggr)^2$$ since $$y=\frac12 at^2$$ So

$$\Delta y=\frac12 \frac{eE}{m}\biggl(\frac{L^2+2LD+D^2}{v_x^2}\biggr) =\frac12 \frac{eE}{m}\biggl(\frac{2LD+L^2}{v_x^2}\biggr)$$ Note here that the author has assumed that since $D$ is very small (compared to the other dimensions) then $D^2\rightarrow 0$

Now if you factor out $\frac{2L}{v_x^2}$ gives $$\Delta y=\frac12 \frac{eE2L}{mv_x^2}({D+\frac{L}{2}})\\
\rightarrow \Delta y=\frac{eEL}{mv_x^2}({D+\frac{L}{2}})$$

Comment: Doesn't $\Delta y=\frac{1}{2}\frac{eE}{m}\biggl(\frac{L+D}{v_x}\biggr)^2$ assume there's an acceleration on the electron the whole time when you use $t=\frac{L+D}{v_x}$?

Comment: There is an acceleration in the y-direction only (the whole time). There is no acceleration in the x-direction, but constant velocity .  This means that t=(L+D)/v_x _is_ a correct expression.

Comment: After the electron leaves the plates, I thought there'd be no electric field (and no force), hence the straight trajectory after leaving the plates

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But how is that relevant to my comment or answer? Even though the electric field no longer exists after leaving the plate, this doesn’t change the fact that v_x is still constant throughout the electrons path. The electrons are _initially_ given velocity in the x-dir v_x and when they enter the plates, there is only a force in the vertical direction. See the very first diagram in the document you linked.

Comment: Yes, $v_x$ is constant. I'm saying that since there's no field after leaving the plates, there's $0$ acceleration in the y-direction after leaving the plates, right? That's why I'm confused--your $\Delta y$ equation has an acceleration through the entire duration (including after leaving the plates). *Why is there an acceleration in the y-direction even after leaving the plates if the field isn't relevant?*

Comment: That's a good question, and it is _exactly_ the reason why I stated that the author has assumed D is small (and it is), meaning $D^2\approx 0$. So we are using the acceleration through the segment $L$ but to a good approximation t=(L+D)/v_x The final expression demands we have L and D in the expression. I would have done it differently, but this is what your teacher has done.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it, my derivation is different because I'm not assuming D is negligible.

Comment: That's  OK and good luck with your studies. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You have found yourself the cause of your misunderstanding,

> ($\sin{\theta}$ is equal to $\frac{\Delta y_1}{L}$ and **probably** equal to $\frac{v_y}{v}$ in the diagram, this could be part of the misunderstanding).

So let me clarify it for you so you really understand.

The only meaningful $\sin{\theta}$ is in fact $\frac{v_y}{v}$ , the local **slope** of the trajectory.

Integrating $v_y$ over the trajectory gives you $\Delta y$, but since $v_y$ is **not** constant over the entire trajectory, the quantity $\frac{\Delta y_1}{L}$ is not **simply** related to $\frac{v_y}{v}$. So $\frac{\Delta y_1}{L}$ is not a useful object during the calculation. It is the **slope** of the curve determined by $\frac{v_y}{v}$ at distance $L$ that gives you $\sin{\theta}$.

In fact, just by looking at the picture, you see that if the slope of the trajectory at $L$ is pushed back to the origin in $x$, you dont hit the initial point, but below that. So the slope is clearly **larger** than $\frac{\Delta y_1}{L}$ !

It turns out the slope is exactly twice this latter value, but this is in fact irrelevant, since $\frac{\Delta y_1}{L}$ is not a useful quantity.Of course ${\Delta y_1}$ is important, but dividing it by $L$ does not tell you anything useful.

Comment: So if $\Delta y_1$ is the y-position increase from where the electron starts (midway between the plates), what do I have to add to $\Delta y_1$ to get $y$?

Comment: Also, yes good catch. The “slope” definitely isn’t $\frac{\Delta y_1}{L}$